# Erro ao enviar objeto do Controller para a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou criando um pequeno projeto em asp.net MVC 5 para treinar e estou tendo problemas na hora de passar um objeto do Controller para a View, está apresentando algum erro relacionado com o método Where<> da biblioteca LINQ.

Erro:

"O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do tipo'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[Projeto01.Models.Usuario]', mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo 'Projeto.Models.Usuario'. "

Action que manda o objeto para a View:

```
private static int userId;

public ActionResult Perfil()
        {
            if (Session["UserEmail"] != null)
            {
                return View(AllUsers.Where(x => x.UsuarioId == userId));
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Default", "Home");
            }
        }
```

Referencia do Objeto na View:

```
@model Projeto01.Models.Usuario
```

OBS: Lembrando que o projeto não usa EntityFramework.

Se for necessário mais alguma informação é só pedir.

Comment: Olha esse link que foi respondido sobre essa questão https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ/47357343#47357343

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `where()` retorna um `IEnumerable<T>`, ou seja, uma coleção de objetos de um tipo determinado, ali no seu caso, um `IEnumerable<Usuario>`.

O problema ali é que a sua view espera um objeto do tipo `Usuario` e você está retornando uma lista deles e como o método `View()` aceita um objeto, ele passa e o alerta vai ser gerado apenas durante a execução.

Para o funcionamento correto você deve fazer da seguinte forma:

`return View(AllUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UsuarioId == userId));`.

O método `FirstOrDefault()` vai retornar o primeiro item da coleção que atenda a condição especificada.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo. Já estava ficando preocupado achando que não tinha sido claro suficiente, o pessoal estava dando dislike, sem deixar nenhum comentário.